# Stack not resolving dependencies properly

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, haskell-stack, hakyll

I'm trying to set up [Hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/01-installation.html) on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 instance, but I can't seem to get the Stack-based setup instructions right.

Starting out with `stack install hakyll`, I get:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for hakyll-4.9.3.0:
    http-conduit-2.1.11 must match >=2.2 && <2.3 (latest applicable is 2.2.3)

Plan construction failed.
```

I got a similar error when tying to `stack-install http-conduit-2.1.11`, this time with:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for http-conduit-2.2.3:
    http-client-0.4.31.2 must match >=0.5 && <0.6 (latest applicable is 0.5.5)
    http-client-tls-0.2.4.1 must match >=0.3 && <0.4 (latest applicable is 0.3.3.1)

Plan construction failed.
```

After resolving dependencies for this (also using Stack), I tried once again to `stack install http-conduit-2.1.11`, but I once again got the same dependency error.

The packages `http-client-0.4.31.2` and `http-client-tls-0.2.4.1` appear in my `~/.stack/precompiled/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/1.24.0.0/`, which isn't explicitly in my `$PATH`, however that feels like an extremely hacky solution, and I haven't found any documentation recommending this approach.

How can I correctly install Hakyll on my machine?

Comment: I understand now that the the purpose of `stack install hakyll` is to get the `hakyll-init` binary. The command failed because `hakyll-4.9.3.0` isn't compatible with the resolver set in your stack.yaml (probably `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`). `hakyll-4.9.3.0` is included in [nightly-2017-01-17](https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2017-01-17) though, so you can `stack --resolver nightly-2017-01-17 install hakyll`. The rest of [the instructions](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/01-installation.html) should work roughly as written.

Comment: BTW there's [a proposal for a `--solver` flag](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2656) that should make installing executables with stack much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution than @sjakobi's in this case was to specify a resolver as a command line option when starting a new Stack project:

```
stack install hakyll --resolver=5.11 --install-ghc
```

Answer (score 3):

Dependency management with stack is meant to be reproducible and declarative, that means that a stack project will only compile once all dependencies are recorded in the .cabal file(s) of the project and once the stack.yaml of the project defines versions for these dependencies either in the [`resolver`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#resolver) or the [`extra-deps`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#extra-deps) section.

Your confusion seems to stem from a misunderstanding of what `stack install` does. The command line help has this to say about it:

```
  build                    Build the package(s) in this directory/configuration
  install                  Shortcut for 'build --copy-bins'
...
  --[no-]copy-bins         Enable/disable copying binaries to the local-bin-path
                           (see 'stack path')
```

`stack install` does *not* save any dependencies.

So the proper way of making hakyll available as a dependency to your code is:

- Create a proper stack project with `stack init` if you already have a Cabal package, or `stack new` if you don't.
- Add `hakyll` to the library or executable `build-depends` in your .cabal file.
- Attempt to `stack build` and follow the instructions in any error messages until all issues are resolved.

Comment: You can install packages with `stack install` though, it just doesn't make the installed packages available to the project.

Comment: @Cubic That depends on what you mean by "install packages". How do you understand it?

Comment: I can `stack install <some-package-name>`, that package will be downloaded, built, I can execute any binaries that are part of the package with `stack exec`... if there's another way to interpret "install packages" I'm not aware of it.